# Accessing WSL2 web services from other machines on the LAN

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, localhost, wsl2

I am having what seems like a familiar issue when trying to access web services running under WSL2 on my Windows 11 PC.

Going back to basics then rather than the more complex scenario that I am ultimately trying to set up.

On my Windows 11 PC I open a terminal and run:

python -m http.server 8080 --bind 0.0.0.0

Accessing this on http://localhost:8080/ I get a directory listing from where I ran that python command as expected. Same for http://127.0.0.1:8080 as expected.

Same for http://192.168.0.200:8080 comes up OK with the IP address.

Now I Ctrl-C out of that python command and turn to Ubuntu 22.04 running under WSL2 on the same host machine.

Again I run "python -m http.server 8080 --bind 0.0.0.0" this time under Ubuntu.

This comes up just fine on http://localhost:8080/ where I get the expected directory listing. Same for http://127.0.0.1:8080 as expected. Also comes up on the 172. address from Ubuntu ifconfig.

However on http://192.168.0.224:8080 it fails with an "Unable to Connect" from Firefox.

Just in case there was an issue with port 8080 specifically I have tried a variety of other ports with the same effect.

I've rebooted many times

I have tried a few things do far. On the Windows 11 side I have:

1. Ensured my Network Profile type for my Ethernet NIC is "Private network"
2. Used netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 to add the 8080 port to the 172 IP address of the WSL Ubuntu instance
3. Went to Control Panel, Windows Defender Firewall and added wsl.exe and wslrelay.exe to the allowed apps through the Firewall
4. In .wslconfig I have added localhostForwarding=true
5. Performed a Network Reset

In Ubuntu I have:

1. Edited /etc/wsl.conf and added the [network] line and the  generateHosts = false line
2. Edited the /etc/hosts file and added ::1   localhost
3. Edited the /etc/hosts file and commented out the  ::1   ip6-localhost ip6-loopback line
4. Added in ::1 localhost

At this point I am all out of ideas. Can anyone suggest what I can try next?

Comment: Check what you did against [this article](https://needlify.com/post/install-and-configure-a-fully-functionnal-web-server-on-wsl-2-b1aa0954) about using Apache in WSL.

Comment: What was the full `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4…` command you used? It feels like maybe something went wrong here.

Comment: The full netsh command was netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8080 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=8080 connectaddress=172.26.207.90